# How to get network bandwidth consumption of each process on Mac

Tags: networking, macos, bandwidth

How can I know each process cost my bandwidth in kb/s?

Activity Monitor of Mac OSX only shows received bytes and send bytes of each process.

Command "nettop" and "nethogs" in Terminal can only show the bandwidth of each connection.

I want to know the bandwidth consumption in kb/s.

Any tool recommendation is appreciated. GUI or command line tool, 
free or Proprietary application are all OK for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nettop can actually do this by activating "delta mode".  Just run `sudo nettop -d` and it will show you the current bandwidth usage instead of the running total. Or press `d` when nettop is open to toggle this. (press `h` to see more shortcuts)

That said if you want a better solution for $$$, [iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) seems like it will do exactly what you want. It shows you the current bandwidth usage broken down by the process. Frustratingly it doesn't tally up the total bandwidth on a per-process level, but as you noted there are other tools for that.

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, "delta mode" is close to an instantaneous measure of bandwidth usage, and the non-delta mode is cumulative since the start of the command. I tried to confirm this but `man nettop`, `nettop -h`, and an internet search give no details. Could you confirm, ideally with a reference?

Comment: Delta mode prints the number of bytes seen since the last interval, which by default is 1 second. You can configure that with `-s`.